# Push, pop view controller equivalent in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, swiftui, navigationlink

What's equivalent to the `Push` and `Pop` of a `view controller` in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root :

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(Model()))
```

iOS version 13.1 :

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pushed = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Push") {
                    self.model.pushed = true
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), isActive: $model.pushed) { EmptyView() }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        Button("Bring me Back") {
            self.model.pushed = false
        }
    }
}
```

Removing the default back button and adding our own will let us get through, until the bug gets fixed by Apple.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pushed = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Push") {
                    self.model.pushed = true
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), isActive: $model.pushed) { EmptyView() }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        Button("Bring me Back") {
            self.model.pushed = false
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: MyBackButton(label: "Back!") {
            self.model.pushed = false
        })
    }
}

struct MyBackButton: View {
    let label: String
    let closure: () -> ()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.closure() }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                Text(label)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[more to refer](https://swiftui-lab.com/bug-navigationlink-isactive/)

Comment: not working for me for some reason. Also, why do you use binding var $model in "is active", but not for self.model.pushed = false. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: actually, I get this now. In self.model.pushed you are changing the value and in the other one you are observing it.

Comment: Never seen this definition in root controller ....rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(Model())). what if you have more than one model? how do you declare that?

Comment: In the log it says nothing and when I press the button nothing happens.

Comment: Hi @Dhaval here you use the value of `@Published var pushed = false` to Push or Pop between 2 View. What if when i need to do with many Views? Should i create new property same as `pushed` ?